My Bee Nests have no honey and no bees inside them, but also don't stack, what's going on?
I'm currently trying to learn how bees work in Java Minecraft. In my 1.21.1 single player survival world I collected 2 Bee Nests with a Silk Touch Axe at night in a Birch & Oak Forest, though at different nights. The first one had honey inside it, when I found it, which I sheered out while having a campfire below it, the second one had no honey inside it, meaning both are now empty.

When I place those Bee Nests no bees come out at day, even if there are flowers right next to them and no blocks are touching the nests. This seems to indicate there are no bees inside. However if I pick both up and put them in my inventory I am unable to stack them with one another. On the internet I read that you could only stack Bee Nests if they are of the same honey level, which mine are and if they have no bees in them, which mine also seem to be. This is also stated here in the Wiki, under "Stackable". So why can't I stack them? I even made a backup of my world and destroyed both nests by hand, and no bees came out, so clearly there are no bees in them, right?


My Main questions is: Are there bees in my nests or not? If there aren't then why can't I stack them?
But I also wouldn't mind if someone could give me advice on what I might have done wrong collecting those nests in the first place. I thought Silk Touch and going at night is all you needed to do and one of them even had honey in it. I have been playing this world for quite some time now, could the bees just have died from mobs?

Have you tried harvesting them with an empty glass bottle? Btw, if you want to check if there are bees inside you can ignite the beenest, according to the wikia "Igniting a nest or hive allows any bees inside to escape"

Try /data get entity @s SelectedItem while holding each and compare. @pinckerman You can see in the textures that they are not full of honey, so the bottle would not work. But they might have an intermediate level.

The nests have different honey levels, but those aren't visible
Thanks to @FabianRöling I have now used the command:
/data get entity @s SelectedItem

on both of them, with the following result:

As we can see, one of the hives is at honey level 0, while the other is at level 3. So as they are at different levels, they can't be stacked.
As I am new with Bee Nests, I was under the assumption that every honey level would look visually different, but that turned out to be false. The honey level only changes once the hive is full, which is at level 5 every other level looks the same as being empty. The wiki article has this to say, emphasis mine:

When the bee exits, the hive increments its honey level by 1 and has a 1% chance to increment it by 2. Once it has the maximum honey level of 5, it changes its appearance to show honey oozing out

Update: In the very next Minecraft Version (1.21.2) the developers have now added the number of  Bees and Honey in them, to the tooltop of both Bee Hives and Nests when you hover over them in your inventory, helping out anyone with a similar problem as mine in the future.

This is an undocumented change, that does not appear in the official patch notes, but is listed on the wiki. In addition to that Bee Nests and Hives are now also visually shown as full in your inventory when they are at Honey level 5, apparently they weren't before.
For anyone interested, I have also learned that the Website Vanilla Tweaks offers a Resource Pack Option, that adds a unique texture to Hives and Nests at Honey levels 1 through 4, i.e. those between empty and full. Which is what I had originially envisioned the base game to have. It's found here under
Utility -> Visual Honey Stages.

Nests with the same honey level do stack together, and I use this to identify empty nests: If you have many stacks of nests in your inventory, the stack with the largest number is most probably the one with no bees and zero honey.

Regarding your closing questions, bees are finnicky. They often get lost in a maze of tree canopies or get themselves killed.
To get a nest with bees inside, search the area with a flower in your hand and lure any bees to to a nest you want to pick. With a bit of luck, whey will use it. Plant a patch of flowers by the nest, so the bees do not have to travel far. Shear tree leaves if they get stuck. Then wait for the evening.

The funny thing is: I went through those woods again and found no bees and no more nests. Then I gave up on it and instead followed a cartographers map to a woodland mansion. On the way I saw atleast 10 bees flying around on an almost empty ocean with no nests in sight. But this was a different direction all together. So when I am done with my trip I will go and get some of those bees, so I can finally have some myself.

@TreeSpawned if I want bees, I usually... plant some trees next to flowers. I would have to check the wiki to be 100% sure, but I believe it was a 5% chance for any oak or birch tree that grows from a sapling next to (or near?) a flower to spawn with a bee hive (including bee). So go out there with some dandelions and saplings, and (on average) 20 trees later you'll have a beehive with inhabitant. And once you have two, you can breed them with flowers.

@Syndic from wiki: "Oak, birch, or cherry trees grown from saplings that are within 2 blocks (including diagonally) of a flower on the same Y-level have a 5% chance to grow with a bee nest containing 2–3 bees. This holds true in any biome in any dimension, and for any flower including wither roses and flowering azaleas. "

@TreeSpawned I literally have 0 idea what the bees in Minecraft are doing. I was traveling far from home a while ago, and I saw one leave it's hive. I gave it a dinnerbone name tag just for fun, and three Minecraft days later, I made it back home, and it was right there at my front door. I think the bee was moving, and it liked my house (which, honestly looked like one of those beehive blocks, lol).

@Syndic Saplings naturally grow beehives? When Minecraft makes no sense at all (which is most of the time)

I think he meant bee nests, which simulates bees colonizing holes in trees.
